# Use grep to find out info

Tags: r, grepl

I want to use grep function to find out some position for example like this:

```
x=c("NCL","NCL,a","a,NCL","NCL-a","a-NCL","FNCL","Ncl")

grep("[NCL]",x)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

However I want the result is

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Hopefully someone can help me thx.

Comment: Try `grep("NCL",x)`.

Comment: We need to know *why* you don't want 6 and 7.  Please add explanation to your question.

Comment: Add a word boundary on both sides and don't ignore case. `grep("\\bNCL\\b",x, ignore.case = F)`.

Comment: I have a list of Gene. Some samples have two names which are separated by comma or dash. like 1 to 5. Some name have overlap like NCL, Ncl and FNCL. But there are totally different.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep('\\bNCL\\b',x)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please edit your answer to add some explanation.